# What's the most efficient way to access the value of a match?

Tags: c#, regex, match

There are many ways to access a `Match`'s value in C#:

```
Match mtch = //whatever
//you could do
mtch.Value
//or 
mtch.ToString()
//or
mtch.Groups[0].Value
//or 
mtch.Groups[0].ToString()
```

My question is: what is the best way to access it?

(I know this is micro-optimization, I'm just wondering)

Comment: Well this seems fairly easy for you to test yourself with appropriate sample data from the regex you're actually interested in. How did those tests go?

Comment: Tests went like this:    
`Match.ToString(): 13823982
Match.Value: 11846245
Match.Groups[0].Value: 22549607
Match.Groups[0].ToString(): 22549607`
(ticks). Why I'm intrigued is why Value and ToString were EXACTLY the same, because that must mean they must both have the EXACT same code in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a quick test and ended up with the following result...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GenericTest()
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(".def.");
        Match mtch = r.Match("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string a = mtch.Value;                  // 15.4%
            string b = mtch.ToString();             // 19.2%
            string c = mtch.Groups[0].Value;        // 23.1%
            string d = mtch.Groups[0].ToString();   // 38.5%
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, how did you get the time split? Just wondering.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Performance Analyzer (Function Details -> Inclusive Samples %) -- The more I run it the more variance in results I get. However, it appears that going into the "Groups" array is where it is slower. Sometimes Value and ToString() end up with exact matches. Sometimes Value overtakes .ToString(). In general though, the array is consistently slower, and the .ToString() is typically slower as well.

Comment: i wonder why your test is not nearly close to my test :) i would guess your `string a` inside the `for` cause this error but string is immutable so it should not be that big difference

Comment: I get 16.2%, 20.3%, 28.6%, and 30.4% when I run your test WhileTrueSleep. (Granted I was impatient and ended the test after about 30 seconds)  I don't know why your first is so quick!

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a test
2. Read result
3. Think about result

If you don't want to write tests look at the Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) and think about what will take more time

---

i also tested it with the result

```
            // VS 2012 Ultimate
            // 
            Regex r = new Regex(".def.");
            Match mtch = r.Match("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 0);
            string a, b, c, d;
            for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
               a = mtch.Value;                  // 1.4%
               b = mtch.ToString();             // 33.2%
               c = mtch.Groups[0].Value;        // 15.3%
               d = mtch.Groups[0].ToString();   // 44.1%
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about effiecency based on the samples you provide I would guess that the most efficient would be the first one since when you use `ToSting()` it adds an extra conversion functionality to your variable which would take an extra time,

Comment: Actually, `Match.ToString()` is returning `this.Value` (you can check it out with an assembly decompiler such as ILSpy or Reflector), so it's only slower because it requires an extra method invocation.